# How can I resolve these Rails gem dependecies after adding rmre 0.0.4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler, dependency-management

I made a new rails 3.2.8 app and added:

```
gem "rmre", "~> 0.0.4"
```

to this new gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.8'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'mysql2'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem "rmre", "~> 0.0.4"

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
```

Running bundle install yields:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "erubis":
  In Gemfile:
    rmre (~> 0.0.4) ruby depends on
      erubis (~> 2.6.6) ruby

    rails (= 3.2.8) ruby depends on
      erubis (2.7.0)
```

I tried commenting out the version numbers and even removing the gems related to asset management.  Still, I can't seem to arrive at a combination of gem versions that work here.  It's the first time I've run into this sort of situation and I am not sure what else I might do to try out the rmre gem with a version of rails that is at least 3-point-something.

Is there a clever way to search for a workable dependency resolution here?  If there is not a gem version configuration that meets the recommended dependencies, is there a least-bad approach to pursue?

Many thanks!

Comment: You might try contacting the `rmre` gem author to see if they would be willing to loosen the dependency restriction, so that it's not tied to such a narrow `erubis` version. Forward compatibility is part of what gem authors need to maintain if they want their gem to continue to work with the latest versions of rails.

Comment: Thanks.  Done.  Post here: https://github.com/bosko/rmre/issues/10

Comment: Is there a way to ask bundler to 'just use it anyway' or is that wrong thinking?

Comment: I'm not super up on gem development, but I don't think it works that way. The reason I believe this is twofold: (1) The gem declares modules and classes that are probably the same names between the various versions of the gem. Trying to load multiple versions of the same gem (one each to satisfy the dependency needs of both the `rmre` and `rails` gems) creates naming conflicts. (2) You would need a way to tell bundler which version of the gem to load, and then override the other gem's dependency declaration.

Comment: You could accomplish #2 by altering the gem that's installed on your machine, but this presents multiple problems. Among them are having to make the same change in development, staging, and production servers, as well as not really knowing if doing this would fix the problem or create a subtle bug somewhere else. On the one hand you have to trust that the gem authors chose their dependency versions appropriately, and on the other hand you have to open cases to get continued support to work when dependencies are sub-optimal. I really think the best thing to do is to try to get the gem updated.

Comment: Thanks n.  I guess there's no way to fork the gem, do nothing but rename it, and then use it as is?  Is this bucking of the system not to be encouraged?

Comment: I guess it depends on how badly you need that gem and/or how badly you need to be on Rails 3.2.8. Sure, you can fork it and republish it under a new name, but that's almost the same as getting the original author to fix it (or you forking it and submitting a pull request). So unless the gem's author is completely unresponsive, I would just go through the normal channels. Is there a reason your app needs to be on 3.2.8, like right now, today? I mean, you could use a previous version of Rails, and perhaps satisfy the dependency requirements that way until the gem is updated.

Comment: To say it another way, I wouldn't say that it's "bucking the system" or whatever - open source is open source - do what you like with it. It's more a matter of how much work you want to put into it vs. the urgency of this issue vs. alternative short-term solutions. If you're using a bug tracker for your project it would (maybe) be as simple as downgrading to a previous version of Rails, getting all the dependencies worked out (of course you might run into another dependency hell if you downgrade - there are no guarantees), and opening a case to upgrade when the `rmre` gem is updated.

Comment: Just finished an exchange with the developer 'Bosko' here https://github.com/bosko/rmre/issues/10  Issue is now closed.  Amazing.  If you like, please post your suggestion as the answer and I'll be happy to accept it as correct.  Best -  Perry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try contacting the rmre gem author to see if they would be willing to loosen the dependency restriction, so that it's not tied to such a narrow erubis version. Forward compatibility is part of what gem authors need to maintain if they want their gem to continue to work with the latest versions of rails. – normalocity Nov 2 at 1:31
.
.
Worked.

Answer (score 0):

Download the zip file from the page. Then execute the gem command. Worked for me. Incredible program.